# Scope for "raise" without arguments in nested exception handlers in Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, python-3.x, scope

Consider the following minimal example:

```
try:
  raise Exception('foo')
except Exception:
  try:
    raise Exception('bar')
  except Exception:
    pass
  raise
```

Running this code with Python 2 raises exception bar, running it with Python 3 raises exception foo. Yet, the documentation for both [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise) states that `raise` with no expression will raise "the last exception that was active in the current scope". Why is the scope different in Python 2 and 3? Is the difference documented anywhere?

Comment: You can see the 2.x vs. 3.x changes to exceptions at https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changes-to-exceptions

Comment: Thanks. It seems that this relates to the implicit cleanup of exception names from blocks introduced by PEP 3110 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/ and mentioned in the documentation with a change between 2 and 3: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#try https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try. Yet this is incomplete at best, because it claims that this only applies to exceptions assigned using "as target".

Comment: Behavior difference verified in 2.7.9 and 3.4.3rc1.  Can you raise an issue on the tracker (bugs.python.org)?  (If not one already.)

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: done: http://bugs.python.org/issue23556

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scopes are different because Python 3 is more advanced.  :)

The scope for `bar` starts with the indented `try`, and ends after the last statement in its `except` clause (or `finally` clause had there been one); the bare `raise` is clearly in the `foo` `except` stanza, and that is what is reraised.

This is one of those little things that was fixed in Python 3.  The docs could be clearer, though.

Comment: OK, I agree that the Python 3 way is more intuitive. I essentially wanted confirmation that this was known and that the documentations should be improved, so I guess there is nothing more to say until issue 23556 is dealt with by the Python people. Thanks!